# Create new div onClick, if not already created

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

```
launchApp: function() {
    $("#app1").on('click', function() {
        if (win === undefined) {
            var win = new AppWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

Every time I click on my `<div/>` with `ID #app1`, a new `<div/>` (window) is created. My problem is that `win` is ALWAYS `undefined`!

How do I do this without assigning `win` to global scope?

Comment: You could wrap it in a closure, add the property win to your object, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make win a 'member function'? Like so

```
launchApp: function() {
    var that = this;
    $("#app1").on('click', function() {
        if (that.win === undefined) {
            that.win = new AppWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

Can you provide more details on your problem to better assist you?